# Как получить доступ к маркеру тек. позиции?

Tags: android

Как получить доступ к маркеру тек. позиции?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу добавить в этому маркеру текст. Или вообще icon поменять. Через Drawable можно сделать. но как мне получить доступ к ней? Нет такой функции в GoogleMap

Comment: Синяя точка не меняется вообще. Можно только свою метку ставить на нее, каждый раз и поменять картинку метки.

Comment: @iFr0z, А как тогда можно убрать синую точку? Просто если я поставлю метку на эту метку, ТО будет смотреться на красиво, ну вы понимаете...

Comment: `map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);`